# Preposition with 'claim': 'to' or 'on'?

Tags: prepositions

What is the correct preposition to be used in the blank? Is it *to* or *on*?

> My cousins have a claim ***_*_** our property.

Comment: It depends on the context. In the given example, as it sounds, the right preposition is *on*. However, the cousins' claim *to* your property could be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

A claim *to* the property implies that it is really their property and your possession is a trespass. A claim *on* the property is a different allegation, for instance that the property should be sold because of a defaulted mortgage or mechanics' lien and they repaid from the proceeds. Your property has been used as security, but their right may not be to the full value.

Answer (score 1):

The different prepositions change the meaning, as Kris surmises in comments.

*Claim **to:*** ownership is probably disputed;
*Claim **on:*** ownership is probably not disputed, but some other claim exists.

ODO is unhelpful, but OED has

> **claim** *noun*
>   **2.** Right of claiming; right or title (*to* something or *to* have, be, or do something; also *on, upon* the person, etc., that the thing is claimed from).

Answer (score 1):

Claim to is making a demand. If, say, the property was left to you by your ancestors, your cousins can make a demand to own it - I.e. Without invoking a right to own it.

Claim on is slightly different in the sense that it is used to make an asssertion of one's right. If the property really does belong to them by law, or they prove thier right to it, claim on is used.

This is the reasons why it is claim to fame and not claim on fame. However, it could be claim to the throne as well as claim on the throne. Thus, in this case too, claim to and claim on are perfectly correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

I would use either *on* or *to* here.  Both mean roughly the same, and are correct in this instance.

*To* is probably the more commonly used.

For example:  You would say lay claim to.  Claim to fame.  Claim to be.

But, claim on something is not wrong.  Just less common.

Comment: They probably mean slightly different things and find usage in different contexts. Need to check.

Comment: @Kris In my experience they are fairly interchangeable.  Claim on your property means that they can say they have a right to it.  Claim to your property, same meaning.  There may be legalese differences, but I doubt it.  A google search for either term does not turn up anything but the definition for claim.  Were there significant difference, it would likely be noted in the dictionary entries.

Comment: lay claim **to**: 44.70M; lay claim **on**: 01.26M; claim **to**: 22.80M; claim **on**: 02.28M. (context not considered).

Comment: So the context does matter, after all.

Comment: @Kris Well, you definitely say claim to fame.  Not claim on fame.  Perhaps we'll just agree that to works here and move on?

Comment: My point was that the preposition makes a difference and hence depends on the context and the intended meaning.

Comment: @Kris In the usage above, it doesn't really matter.  In others, yes it does.  But, I've edited to make it a bit easier for an English Language Learner